# How to dynamically calculate nodes and edges for vis.js

Tags: javascript, vis.js

I am fighting with right method how to properly defined data for a diagram from a query result.

unfortunately I am still getting only one empty circle in the result.

```
obj = JSON.parse(response);
  $.each(obj.aggregations.system.buckets, function(s, system) {
    if (system.doc_count != 0) {
      var nodes_tmp = [],
      edges_tmp = [],
      firs_id = '',
      prev_id = '',
      last_id = '';                     

      $.each(system.platformSteps.buckets, function(st, step) {
        id = st+1;
        nodes_tmp.push("{id: " + id + ", label: '" + step.key +"'}");

        if (st != 0) {
            edges_tmp.push("{from: " + prev_id + ", to: " + id +"}");
        } else {
            edges_tmp.push("{from: " + id + ", to: '" + id +"'}");
        }

        prev_id = id;
      }); // Loop platform steps

      nodes = new vis.DataSet([nodes_tmp]);
      edges = new vis.DataSet([edges_tmp]),

      var container = document.getElementById('mynetwork');
      var data = {
           nodes: nodes,
           edges: edges
      };
      var options = {};
      var network = new vis.Network(container, data, options);
    }; // If system.doc_count != 0
  }); // Loop systems
```

When I debugged the generated object I am getting different structure of nodes data:

> - nodes
>
>   - _data
>
>     - 3925b97c-cc43-45f4-8b2c-99773a0960e6
>
>       - 0: "{id: 1, label: 'AIBFULLTRACE'}"
>       - 1: "{id: 2, label: 'euCyclone'}"
>       - id: "3925b97c-cc43-45f4-8b2c-99773a0960e6"

But in demo the schema is:

> - nodes
>
>   - _data
>
>     - 1: Object
>
>       - id:1
>       - label:"Node 1"
>     - 2: Object
>
>       - id:2
>       - label:"Node 2"

What I am doing wrong with the assignment there?

Thanks, Reddy

**FIXED by using eval() and .add() methods:**

```
                        var node_tmp = {},
                                edge_tmp = {},
                                node_txt = '',
                                edge_txt = '',
                            firs_id = '',
                                prev_id = '',
                                last_id = '';       
                        var nodes = new vis.DataSet(node_tmp);
                        var edges = new vis.DataSet(edge_tmp);                                                      

                        $.each(system.platformSteps.buckets, function(st, step) {
                            id = st+1;

                            if (st == 0) {
                                node_txt = '({id: ' + id + ', label: \'' + step.key +'\',shape: \'box\', first: true})';
                        } else {
                                node_txt = '({id: ' + id + ', label: \'' + step.key +'\',shape: \'box\'})';
                            }
                            node_tmp = eval(node_txt);
                            nodes.add(node_tmp);

                            if (st != 0) {
                                edge_txt = '({from: ' + prev_id + ', to: ' + id +',arrows:\'to\', label:\'to\'})';
                                edge_tmp = eval(edge_txt);
                                edges.add(edge_tmp);
                            } else {
                                //edges_tmp.push("{from: " + id + ", to: '" + id +"'}");
                            }
                            //console.log(edges_tmp.toString());

                            prev_id = id;
                        }); // Loop platform steps
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**FIXED by using eval() and .add() methods:**

```
                        var node_tmp = {},
                                edge_tmp = {},
                                node_txt = '',
                                edge_txt = '',
                            firs_id = '',
                                prev_id = '',
                                last_id = '';       
                        var nodes = new vis.DataSet(node_tmp);
                        var edges = new vis.DataSet(edge_tmp);                                                      

                        $.each(system.platformSteps.buckets, function(st, step) {
                            id = st+1;

                            if (st == 0) {
                                node_txt = '({id: ' + id + ', label: \'' + step.key +'\',shape: \'box\', first: true})';
                        } else {
                                node_txt = '({id: ' + id + ', label: \'' + step.key +'\',shape: \'box\'})';
                            }
                            node_tmp = eval(node_txt);
                            nodes.add(node_tmp);

                            if (st != 0) {
                                edge_txt = '({from: ' + prev_id + ', to: ' + id +',arrows:\'to\', label:\'to\'})';
                                edge_tmp = eval(edge_txt);
                                edges.add(edge_tmp);
                            } else {
                                //edges_tmp.push("{from: " + id + ", to: '" + id +"'}");
                            }
                            //console.log(edges_tmp.toString());

                            prev_id = id;
                        }); // Loop platform steps
```